# Chi Square Test of Independence of Whole Dataset

Tags: r, for-loop, chi-squared

I have a 3185x90 dataset of binary values and want to do a chi-squared test of independence, comparing all column variables against each other.

I've been tried using different variations of code from google searches with  `chisq.test()` and some for loops, but none of them have worked so far.

How do I do this?

This is the frame I've tinkered with. My dataset is oak.

```
chi_trial <- data.frame(a = c(0,1), b = c(0,1))
for(row in 1:nrow(oak)){
  print(row)
  print(chisq.test(c(oak[row,1],d[row,2])))
}
```

I also tried this:

```
apply(d, 1, chisq.test)
```

which gives me the error: Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite

```
dput(oak[1:2],)
structure(list(post_flu = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

label = "Receipt of Flu Vaccine - Encounter Survey", format.stata = "%10.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3185L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), label = "Main Oakland Clinic Analysis Dataset")
```

I added a sample of my data with the final lines of the output. The portion of the dataset is small, but it all looks like this.

Comment: Hi Joseph, it's not clear what rows or columns you want to perform the `chisq.test` on. Can you please clarify? How do you intend to correct for multiple testing? Additionally, it will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data `dput(d[1:20,])`. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: I second Ian's comment. Also, you say your goal is "comparing all variables", but the comparisons in your for-loop are row-wise. Data frame rows are observations, while *columns* are variables. χ2 also doesn't really make sense for observation-wise comparisons, as a rule, although I suppose there might be occasional exceptions.

Comment: +1 to both @IanCampbell (and gersht).  Even if you get an answer to your specific question, that may not be doing you a service in the long run.  You have deeper issues to consider before you can be sure that what you are doing is correct or appropriate.

Comment: I added some data. I want to know if there are significant differences in variable/column frequencies. Lastly, I don't plan on having a career in coding; using r is required for the research I'm doing this summer. The code I use usually comes from other stacked posts, so I'm unsure of which ones will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the code below, which is similar to R's `cor` function. I don't have your data, so I'm simulating some. Note that I get one significant p-value, using the traditional cut-off of 0.05.

```
set.seed(3)
nr=3185; nc=3

oak <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, size=nr*nc, replace=TRUE), ncol=nc))
oak

mult.chi <- function(data){
  nc <- ncol(data)
  res <- matrix(0, nrow=nc, ncol=nc) # or NA
  for(i in 1:(nc-1))
    for(j in (i+1):nc)
      res[i,j] <- suppressWarnings(chisq.test(oak[,i], oak[,j])$p.value)
  rownames(res) <- colnames(data)
  colnames(res) <- colnames(data)
  res
}

mult.chi(oak)

#    V1        V2         V3
# V1  0 0.7847063 0.32012466
# V2  0 0.0000000 0.01410326
# V3  0 0.0000000 0.00000000
```

So consider applying a multiple testing adjustment as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `combn` to get all combinations of column numbers 2 by 2. Tested with the data in [@Edward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62368589/8245406).

```
chisq2cols <- function(X){
  y <- matrix(0, ncol(X), ncol(X))
  cmb <- combn(ncol(X), 2)
  y[upper.tri(y)] <- apply(cmb, 2, function(k){
    tbl <- table(X[k])
    chisq.test(tbl)$p.value
  })
  y
}

chisq2cols(oak)
#     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,]    0 0.7847063 0.32012466
#[2,]    0 0.0000000 0.01410326
#[3,]    0 0.0000000 0.00000000
```